# Testing Vee-Validate confirmed rule

Tags: vue.js, mocha.js, vee-validate, vue-test-utils

I am having some difficulty in testing a Vee-Validate confirmed function on a Vue form built with Vuetify. The component that I  am trying to test looks like this:

```
<template>
    <form novalidate ref="loginForm" v-model="formValid" @submit.stop.prevent="formSubmitted" @keyup.enter="formSubmitted">
      <v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center>
        <v-layout column>
          <v-flex>
            <v-text-field
              name="passwordField"
              label="Enter your Password"
              hint="At least 6 characters"
              v-model="submissionDetails.password"
              :type="passwordShown ? 'text' : 'password'"
              min="6"
              required
              :append-icon="passwordShown ? 'visibility_off': 'visibility'"
              :append-icon-cb="()=>(passwordShown = !passwordShown)"
              v-validate="'required|min:6'"
              data-vv-name="password"
              :error-messages="errors.collect('password')"
              ref="password"
              @change="inputTriggered"
              @input="inputTriggered"
            />
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex v-show="createAccountTicked">
            <v-text-field
              name="confirmPasswordField"
              label="Confirm your Password"
              hint="At least 6 characters"
              v-model="confirmPassword"
              :type="passwordShown ? 'text' : 'password'"
              min="6"
              required
              :append-icon="passwordShown ? 'visibility_off': 'visibility'"
              :append-icon-cb="()=>(passwordShown = !passwordShown)"
              v-validate="'required|confirmed:$password'"
              data-vv-name="confirmPassword"
              :error-messages="errors.collect('confirmPassword')"/>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </form>
  </template>
  <script>
  export default {
    name: 'email-password-form',
    data () {
      return {
        submissionDetails: {
          email: '',
          password: ''
        },
        confirmPassword: '',
        passwordShown: false,
        createAccountTicked: false
      };
    }
  };
</script>
```

The above works fine with the error messages being displayed on the screen correctly and removed when the passwords match, but the below test fails:

```
 describe.only('validation', () => {
    it('should not attach an error to confirm password when it does match the password', async () => {
      const wrapper = mount(EmailPasswordForm, { localVue });
      wrapper.setData({
        submissionDetails: {
          password: 'wwwwww'
        },
        createAccountTicked: true,
        confirmPassword: 'wwwwww'
      });
      // await wrapper.vm.$validator.validateAll();
      // await wrapper.vm.$validator.validate('password');

      await wrapper.vm.$validator.validate('confirmPassword');

      console.log(wrapper.vm.errors.collect('confirmPassword'));
      // ['The confirmPassword confirmation does not match.']

      console.log(wrapper.vm.submissionDetails.password === wrapper.vm.confirmPassword);
      // true

      expect(wrapper.vm.errors.has('confirmPassword')).to.be.false;
      // AssertionError: expected true to be false
    });
  });
```

As can be seen from the above code, it appears that while the password and confirmPassword strings do match, the validator still flags the confirm password field as having an error. I can't understand why that might be but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So it turns out that this behaviour is due to how Vee-Validate compares values for multi-field validation, and how those values are propagated. (See [this issue](https://github.com/baianat/Vee-validate/issues/1015))

The easiest solution was to use the new `is` validation rule, which allows me to compare against the model, instead of the contents of the field. I just changed the `v-validate` rule contents from `'required|confirmed:$password'` to `v-validate="{required: true, is: submissionDetails.password}"`

I'll leave this here in case anyone else has this issue.

Comment: Thank you! I've spent hours on this. :/

Answer (score 1):

On my case, either one of this two methods works for me:

```
<input 
 v-validate="{ required : true,  confirmed: 'password'}" 
 type="password" name="confirm_password"  
 class="form-control" 
 placeholder="Confirm Password" 
 v-model="field.confirm_password" 
 data-vv-as="confirm password">

<input 
 v-validate="{ required : true,  confirmed: field.password}" 
 type="password" name="confirm_password"  
 class="form-control" 
 placeholder="Confirm Password" 
 v-model="field.confirm_password" 
 data-vv-as="confirm password">
```

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed the problem I was having in chrome with the validation errors showing up even when disabled with Chrome, due to the combination of `required` and `confirmed:password` as `v-validate="'required|confirmed:password'"`

```
 <input

 v-validate="{ required : true,  confirmed: field.password}" 

 type="password" name="confirm_password"  
 class="form-control" 
 placeholder="Confirm Password" 
 v-model="field.confirm_password" 
 data-vv-as="confirm password">
```